# Reinitialising content script after Ajax load?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, dynamically-generated

In my content script, I am going through the entire DOM and doing something to all `<img>` elements for example.

I am using `onUpdated` in my `Background.js` to check when a tab is opened and then executing the script.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) { 
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            if(info.status == "complete") {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, function (response) {
                   // send data to content script etc.
                });
            }
        });
}
```

This works fine for content that isn't dynamically loaded - for example, on the Facebook news feed, it'll do what I want to all the images that are initially visible - but as I scroll down, new stories/photos etc are  loaded (using AJAX? unsure) and of course these `<img>` elements are not affected by my content script.

How can I reload (or adjust would be better as I have to search the entire DOM and it's slow) my content script so that it works for this newly adjusted DOM? I couldn't find any tabs method here - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs mentioning this issue.

Tried:

- adding `all_frames : true` in the `manifest` does nothing.
- removing the info.status conditional also does nothing.

Comment: Your code is definitely strange. Why do you get `tabs[0].id` and the whole query thing when `tabId` is passed into the listener?

Comment: @Xan It's not my whole code just the essentials for this question, I am passing a lot of chrome.storage stuff through but yeah you are right will change it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to monitor the page for insertion of new images, for instance using `MutationObserver` or `mutation-summary` library. `tabs` events will not fire on page changes like those.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener) for a discussion of methods to do so.